# Simple harmonic motion net force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, harmonic-oscillator

I was doing some practice questions for a physics test I have tomorrow. I encountered the following question:
[image]

However, I was quite sure the answer was B, as in position B gravity is being contrasted by tension and there are no other forces. I think I am missing something obvious or is the mark scheme wrong?

Comment: the resultant (the sum of the weight and the reaction of the wire) is never zero, unless the bob is at rest in the stable equilibrium position. See my answer below

Comment: To put it another way: Only the angular acceleration is zero at point B, so only the angular component of the net force is zero. The radial acceleration is not zero at point B because the object is still undergoing circular motion and so the radial acceleration must be $v^2/L$ and $v$ is not zero (so the radial net force is not zero, and thus the overall magnitude of the net force is not zero). (This means, for example, that the tension in the string at point B is *greater than* $mg$.) (By the way, this is a bit of a tricky question. It certainly tricked me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the acceleration equal to zero in $B$?

No, it's not, since the radial component of the equations of motion in $B$ reads

$0 \ne -m R \dot\theta_B^2 = mg - T_B = F_{r,B}^{tot}$

For completeness, the radial and azimuthal components of the equation of motion of the mass are

$\hat{r}: - m R \dot\theta^2 = T - mg \cos \theta = F_r^{tot}$
$\hat{\theta}: m R \ddot \theta = - mg \sin \theta = F_{\theta}^{tot}$

Comment: two downvotes in 1 minute, without a comment, on a right answer. Great

Comment: is it going on a straight line? The only way to have no radial acceleration is if it doesn't move. Or if it's going straight

Comment: The question asks about the "net force," right?

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but I don't see how this answers the question...

Comment: Please, be serious. And reduce the speed in commenting and deleting the comments (where you asserted zero acceleration, since then it seems that I'm replying to ghosts) and maybe downvoting

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Only the angular acceleration is zero at B, and only the angular component of the net force is zero. You are correct. Nevertheless you are incorrect about me having a downvote on this answer.

Comment: And now you have an up-vote from me ;) (Net is still zero, unfortunately)

Comment: How the hell is zero in $B$? Now I'm going sleeping. Obviously I'm talking not in a D'Alembert point of view: net force doesn't include inertia, otherwise it's always zero. oh, net vote. It's too late. It's better if I go to sleep

Comment: Sorry for the harsh comments before. But downvoting without a comment makes me crazy, since it doesn't even give me a hint about the possible mistake. And there is no way to improve

Comment: Yeah, I meant net vote on your answer is still zero. The down vote is probably because some people downvote whenever someone answers a homework question.